# Convergence of an rcll process along a random subsequence

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I have a process $X_s$, for $s \ge 0$, taking values in a Polish space $T$ with an rcll version where I have shown, for every nonrandom increasing sequence $s_n$, that $X_{s_n} \to c$ in probability, where $c$ is non-random (it's a parameter actually that determines the law of the process X indirectly).

**Here is the question:** There is a natural sequence of a.s. increasing and diverging optional times $\tau_n$. What tricks are there for establishing convergence in probability of X along the random sequence $\tau$?

If it is useful, we may even assume that $X_s$ is a pure jump process and, for every $s \ge 0$, $X_s$ is $Y_s$-measurable where $Y_s$ is a pure-jump Markov process. The "natural sequence of optional times" would then be the jumps of $X_s$, which are always jumps of $Y_s$.

Comment: Can you be very precise in defining what you have and what you want?  For instance, in the first paragraph, do you have $X_{s_n} \to c$ i.p. for deterministic sequences of $s_n$ only, or random sequences?  What precise statement are you looking for in #1?  Note that the statement "$X_s \to c$ almost surely" does not get you #2 either: convergence along random sequences is much much stronger, and might need something like $L^\infty$ convergence.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail. Part of the issue is that I need guidance for what I should be trying to prove, so I may be far from showing what I need to show.

Comment: I don't understand your use of the word "simultaneous" in 1.  The usual interpretation of "convergence as $s \to \infty$" would be: for every $\epsilon$ we have $\lim_{s \to \infty} P(d(X_s, c)>\epsilon) = 0$.  That is, for every $\delta$ and every $\epsilon$ there exists $s_0$ such that for all $s > s_0$ we have $P(d(X_s, c) > \epsilon) < \delta$.  But you get that for free from the assumption that $X_{s_n} \to c$ i.p. for all nonrandom sequences $s_n$.  If that is not what you want, please state *even more precisely* where the quantifiers should go.

Comment: OK, I see the issue. I was trying to anticipate a useful intermediate result, akin to $\Pr \{ \forall s_n \to \infty X_{s_n} \to c \} = 1$.  Let's ignore the intermediate result.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge: too little structure still?

Comment: The question is clear now, I just don't have any suggestions as to the answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: OK, glad that it is finally clear.